# Compiling a Contract

Tags: remix, dapps

```
This is my Smart Contract:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

contract DepositContract {
    // The amount of time (in hours) that the contract will run for
    uint256 constant DURATION_HOURS = 24;
    // The payout rate (in percentage per hour)
    uint256 constant PAYOUT_RATE = 4.16666666667;

    // Mapping from user address to their deposit balance
    mapping(address => uint256) public deposits;

    // The total amount of deposits in the contract
    uint256 public totalDeposits;

    // The start time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public startTime;

    // The end time of the contract (in seconds)
    uint256 public endTime;

    // Flag to indicate whether the contract is active
    bool public isActive;

    constructor() public {
        // Set the start and end times of the contract
        startTime = now;
        endTime = startTime + DURATION * 3600;
        // Set the contract to be active
        isActive = true;
    }

    // Function to deposit FTM into the contract
    function deposit() public payable {
        // Check that the contract is still active
        require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
        // Check that the deposit is not zero
        require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit
My smart contract that I'm trying to compile gives me the following error: contracts/DepositContract.sol:38:32: ParserError: Expected string end-quote. require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit ^------^
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The deposit function should look something like this.

```
function deposit() public payable {
    // Check that the contract is still active
    require(isActive, "The contract is no longer active.");
    
    // Check that the deposit is not zero
    require(msg.value > 0, "Deposit non-zero amount");

    //Transfer the value to the contract.
    payable(address(this)).transfer(msg.value);
    
    // Adding deposit total
    totalDeposits += 1;
    
    //Mapping the deposit to the sender.
    deposits[msg.sender] = msg.value;
}
```

Hope this helps!